# Genson not throwing UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: genson

I have json POST request with the following {"token":"abcd","m":"n"} where as the java bean holds:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Token {

    public String token;

}
```

On using Genson, it is not throwing UnrecognizedPropertyException which otherwise happen if i remove Genson dependency from pom.xml

Comment: I am Gensons author, at the moment it will swallow them silently, I opened an issue few time ago https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/13, I'll try to get it in the next release this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest Genson release 1.1, you have now an option in the builder to fail if no property matches:

```
new GensonBuilder().failOnMissingProperty(true).create();
```